# SWT Table, TableViewer, Refreshing Table on Data Change

Tags: java, swt

I am in bad need of some guided assistance.  I have been able to work through and get to work code examples of Tables and TableViewers.  But I am not finding any examples to help me with my particle setup.

Please guide me in the right direction.

My classes:

AHandler.java - This allows the user to select data from a Right Mouse Click.  During the execution I am calling a singleton class to add user selected data to a arraylist.

```
ASelectedData.getInstance().add(tcRevision, selectedDataset);
```

ASelectedData.java - is singleton class where the user selections is added to a ArrayList.

ABase.java - this dialog opens with a menu click.  The dialog should display a table with the values from the ArrayList.  Some buttons that preform other actions.

The way I have it right now is the table and tableviewer is being created in the ABase.java class.  I am pulling the information for the table from.

```
 viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
 viewer.setInput(AplotSelectedDataTable.getInstance().getArrayData());
```

This will populate the table with the correct data.

But the ABase.java class is MODELESS.  So why that dialog is open the user can continue to pick data using the right mouse button and adding to the arraylist.  But the way I have the table coded the I have to reopen the window to update the data.

* EDIT  ******
In my main GUI I have created a TableViewer.  The TableViewer creates a table that displays data from a arraylist in a separate class.  The problem is that the user is still able to go to the Main Application GUI ( not my Application GUI ) and select more data while my GUI is still open.  They expect to see the new data added to the table as they select it.

The problem is there is no way that I know of to tell the table new data has arrived so refresh the table.  The Add method that takes the data and adds it to the ArrayList is in the ASelectedData class.  Not the class the tableviewer is created in.

When the Add Method is executed, I need a way to tell the table to refresh.  The problem is the Table and the Method is in two separate classes.

Hope this makes more sense

**EDIT***

my main GUI with the TableViewer

```
public AplotBaseDialog(Shell shell, TCSession theSession) Constructor

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                         createTableViewer()                          //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private TableViewer createTableViewer(Composite parent) {
   viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
   createColumns(parent, viewer);
   Table table = viewer.getTable();
   table.setHeaderVisible(true);
   table.setLinesVisible(true);

   viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
   viewer.setInput(AplotSelectedDataTable.getInstance().getArrayData());

   // Layout the viewer
   GridData gridData = new GridData();
   gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
   gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
   gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
   gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
   gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
   viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
   return viewer;
 }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                            updateTableViewer()                       //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void updateTableViewer() {
   viewer.refresh();
}
```

The code added to other class

```
  AplotBaseDialog abd = new AplotBaseDialog(null, null);

  public void add(TCComponentItemRevision tcRevision, TCComponentDataset selectedDataset) {
   AplotDatasetData pp = new AplotDatasetData(tcRevision, selectedDataset);
   if (!dataArrayList.contains(pp)) {
      dataArrayList.add(pp);

   }
   abd.updateTableViewer();
  }// end add()
```

Comment: There might be something missing in your question...

Comment: Please tell me and I will do my best to add what it missing

Comment: What exactly is your question? There seems to be something missing at the end of your question.

Comment: You can still use my answer. Just call the `YOURCLASS.updateTableViewer()` method from the `add` method of the model containing the list, which will refresh your tableviewer.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this issue. Would it have been possible to create the table in the class with the Add method and view it from the Main GUI class?

Comment: I would not recommend this. You should keep gui and data-management in separate classes. What's wrong with my idea?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your idea.  I appreciate it very much.  I am just having problems trying to understand how all this table stuff works in SWT.  So just make sure that I understand.  If I have a application window class that needs to display a table.  I have to create a tableviewer in the same class and that includes all the column methods.  Then point my setInput to the actual data structure holding the data.

Comment: All you are saying is correct.

Comment: The new update method is throwing a null pointer.

Comment: Well, without code, I cannot help you...

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: At the viewer.refresh(); call in the main GUI class

Comment: Have you tried adding the null check from my code?

Comment: I did forget to put that check in the Method.  After I put it in I see that viewer must be null

Comment: Does that mean it works? If not, you might want to have a look at the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). This might be useful for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your question is not complete yet, I will try to guess your problem:
You have a `TableViewer` in a `Dialog` and you can edit the `ModelProvider` from the main GUI. Now you want to know how to update the table, when you add something to the model, is that correct?

If so, you can provide a method in the dialog which can update the `TableViewer` in your dialog. Something like this:

```
public void updateTableViewer()
{
    if(viewer != null)
        viewer.refresh();
}
```

You can call this method from your main gui, when you add something to the `ModelProvider`.

If this is not your question, please update your original post.

Comment: I will try and explain the problem better in the original question

Comment: @Baz update dialogbox open after update the value to update database but tableviewer can not display updata record or value. [code] dialog.open(); if(viewer != null)  viewer.refresh(); not working generate error:  org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:

Answer (score 0):

Add this bunch of code in create control it may solve your problem:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(new IResourceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
        treeViewer.refresh();
    }
});
```